# Does $(Ax)(t) = \int_{0}^{t} x(s) ds$ has eigenvectors for $A : C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

The question is as follows:

Consider the operator $A : C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ given by $(Ax)(t) = \int_{0}^{t} x(s) ds.$ Does $A$ has eigenvectors? Also find its spectrum $\sigma(A)?$

$\textbf{Some efforts:}$

If $\lambda \neq 0$ were an eigenvalue of $A$ with an eigenvector $x$, then we have $x(t) = \frac{1}{\lambda} \int_{0}^{t} x(s) ds $. This means that $x$ is absolutly continuous and $x'(t) = \frac{x(t)}{\lambda}$ with initial value $x(0)=0$. This imply that $x(t) = 0$ for $t \in [0,1]$ is the only eigenvector.

And since $\sigma(A)$ can not be empty, we have $\sigma(A) = \{ 0 \}$. And zero is not an eigenvalue of $A$.

Can you please let me know if I have any misunderstanding and if my calculation is wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. $A$ is not surjective, since $y(0)=0$ for all $y \in Im(A)$.
   Hence: $0 \in \sigma(A)$.
2. You are right: if $ \lambda \ne 0$, then $ \lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$.
3. Let $ \lambda \ne 0$. We show that $\lambda I-A$ is surjective. To this end let $y \in C[0,1]$. We are done if there is $x \in C[0,1]$ such that $y=(\lambda I -A)x$. This equation gives

$x'(t)=\frac{1}{\lambda}x(t)+y'(t)$ and $x(0)=\frac{1}{\lambda}y(0)$.

This initial value problem has a unique solution $x$.

Conclusion: $\sigma(A)=\{0\}$.

Comment: Many thanks! Nice answer!